# How can we use service principal as user in Databricks SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks-sql, service-principal, aws-databricks

If I want to run with service principles instead my user id in databricks sql is possible ?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to run as the Service Principal specifically in the web interface, or is a JDBC connection acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for looking this.As like , we can schedule job with service Principal as owner in DataBricks , would like to run the query or Schedule the query with SP in databricks sql